# How to test a private variable inside a method using Mockito or Junit

Tags: java, android, junit, mocking, mockito

I wish to write a test which can confirm that the private title variable will equal "internet connection lost please try again"

```
var title = ""
if (errorMessage.equals("NO_CONNECTION")){
   title = "internet connection lost please try again"
   launchAlertBox(title)
}
```

is this even possible?

}

I tried to use different frameworks like spy and easymock but it did not help me

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It's considered an anti-pattern to test the value of a private part of your code.

Comment: While title is a private variable, it is passed to other function: `launchAlertBox`, which has a visible side effect. Thus, your task is not to check the value of the private variable, but that this function is called with the correct argument. Typically, you provide such functions in the constructor of your object under test, and provide a fake one in a test.